# Anyway to get TestNG to not run a suite if a class method does not exist?

Tags: java, testng, testng.xml

`TestNG (6.14.3)` for some reason will continue to run if one of the class methods doesn't exist.  What it seems to do is just execute the next `@Test` method in the class file.  Is there any way to get TestNG to fail the suite if one of the class test methods does not exist?  In the following suite file, even though one of the test methods does not exist in the class file, it will just pick up what seems to be a random @test method and continue on it's merry way:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="testSuite" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="sProject" value="mine"/>
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="framework.Listener"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="TestSuite-Part1" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.HomePageTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="gotoHomePageTest"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="tests.MiniBannerCardTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="thisMethodDoesNotExist"/>
                    <include name="verifyDeliveryZipCodeSetTest"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="tests.HeaderCardTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="clickSignInOrRegisterLinkTest"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I've tried the following in the `onStart` in a suite listener which works great on the dev machine!  However, there is no `./src/main/java` nor any source files on the runner VM for it to process, so it just aborts saying the path is non-existent. Any ideas?

```
    Log.info("**********About to begin executing suite: " + suite.getName());
    // getting included method names in XML suite file
    List<String> inclduedMethodsInXmlSuite =
            suite.getXmlSuite().getTests().stream()
                  .flatMap(xmlTest -> xmlTest.getClasses().stream().flatMap(xmlClass -> xmlClass.getIncludedMethods().stream().map(XmlInclude::getName)))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // getting all test methods
    List<String> testMethods = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("./src/main/java")))
    { // path to test classes directory
        testMethods = paths
                .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".java")) // filtering only classes, not directories
                .map(path -> path.getParent().getFileName().toString() + "." + path.getFileName().toString()) // mapping to qualified name, e.g test.TestClass
                .map(file -> file.substring(0, file.length() - 5)) // removing ".java"
                .map(clazz ->
                     {
                         try
                         {
                             return Class.forName(clazz); // casting to Class object
                         }
                         catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                         {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                             return null;
                         }
                     }
                    )
                .flatMap(clazz -> Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredMethods()).filter(method -> method.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class)))
                .map(Method::getName) // mapping to method name
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // checking if any of xml suite methods does not exist in test methods
    final List<String> finalTestMethods = testMethods;
    List<String> notSupprtedMethods = inclduedMethodsInXmlSuite.stream()
                                                               .filter(xmlMethod -> !finalTestMethods.contains(xmlMethod))
                                                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (notSupprtedMethods.size() > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("*****=====Unsupported methods in XML Suite file=====*****:");
        notSupprtedMethods.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

**EDIT:**
using `7.4.0` it seems to just skip the missing method rather than run the next one. No log or any indication it had skipped though.

Comment: Please mention the testng version you are using as part of the question

Comment: Updated Original post to include version!

Comment: Maybe a bug. Could you check with latest version `7.4.0`.

Comment: using 7.4.0 it seems to just skip the missing method rather than run the next one.  No log or any indication it had skipped though.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG doesn't check if the method mentioned in `<include>` is available or not. It is actually the other way. i.e. It first picks all the test methods in the specified `<class>`, then for each method it checks whether it is included or excluded in the xml and then execution is carried out based on this data. It does not mark the method as **skipped** because it is not configured to run.

But from your comment, I could understand that you are good if there is some message logged. TestNG does **log** such exclusions.

So when any method is not included in `<include>` tag, it **logs the message at INFO level**. For that, you need to add the below log level in your `log4testng.properties` file.

```
log4testng.logger.org.testng.internal.Utils=INFO
```

Assume that you have `firstTest` method in your test class (package `a.b.c`) and you accidently specified the name as `firsTest` in the xml, then after adding the log properties, the below message would be available.

```
[Utils] [INFO] [XmlMethodSelector] Excluding method a.b.c.firstTest()
```

Also make sure the `verbose` is set to `4` in `<test>`

```
<test name="TestSuite-Part1" preserve-order="true" verbose="4">
```

Comment: Curious.  Say the method is misnamed is the last of say 10 test methods in the suite.  Since this is misnamed (or someone by mistake removed the method from the class) it will just be skipped with nothing buy an info line.  The suite will pass, and QA will sign off on the build even though there was a glaring defect that would have been caught by that test method.  That to me seems very bad, and I know this because it happened to us.  Our tests were passing 100% even though there was a defect which would have been caught if testNG had notified us that the last method was missing.

Comment: @GregMa If you are running it in a production or similar crucial environment, then I personally would suggest against using `<include>` or `<exclude>` in the xml. Why specifically run a few tests? Is there any reason why you do not want to run all test methods?